# Relationship between HostName and DNS entry

Tags: iis, hostname, dns-hosting

I am very new to IIS and Deployment world. We recently deployed a website and I think if I am understanding correctly the URL was determined by two things

- DNS Entry(to me its IP/Name mapping, which helps direct the request to the correct machine)
- HostName(Used it for the first time)

What I noticed is that our admin wanted me to keep the DNS Entry and HostName exactly same for the website. I also noticed that when the Hostname was different than the DNS entry it was not resolving.

So my questions is:

- Does the DNS entry and the HostName always have to be verbatim same?

Comment: `Does the DNS entry and the HostName always have to be verbatim same?` - No, and they rarely are.

Comment: @CoffeBean, I guess yours is a case of name based virtual hosting and you are confusing the HostName entry in IIS with the real server name. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't have to be. The dns entry is a pointer to the host and it has no idea what the host is really named. This entry is used to access the host by a reasonable or understandable *name*.  Of course one can also access it directly with the ip address, but this is not always practical and mostly not wanted.

Think of the case when the same host is possible to access using different names, if it so configured in the dns server that all the different names resolve to the same ip.

In the case of virtual web hosting (or more appropriately saying, name based virtual hosting), when serveral websites are hosted on the same server that is on a single ip address, the HostName entry can be critical. The webserver can only differentiate between the request for different websites based on the hostname that comes in the request header. (But it is not the same as the Servername.  It is more a virtual name (fqdn).

I guess yours is a case of namebased virtual hosting and you are confusing the HostName (fqdn) entry in IIS with the real server-name.

> I also noticed that when the Hostname was different than the DNS entry
>   it was not resolving.

I think this is not correct. When you had a different `HostName` entry, the dns resolution definitely worked. You can check it again with `nslookup`. But your website wasn't reachable.

Have a look here: [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

And [Hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)